# Поиск в двумерном массиве - PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив **$idname**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => One
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Two
        )

)
```

Как получить **name** если знаем только **id**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = array();
$array[] = ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'One'];
$array[] = ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'Two'];

$array2 = array_column($array, 'name', 'id'); // Формируем новый массив
$id = 1; // какой id будем искать
$search = (isset($array2[$id])) ?   $array2[$id]    :   NULL; // поиск
var_dump($search); // Любуемся
```

Answer (score 4):

как-то так видимо?

```
$data = array_column($idname, 'name', 'id');
$result = $data[2]; // two
```

можно, конечно, и простыми циклами с проверкой значения, и всякие `array_filter` и `array_reduce` и т.п.

Но если  из массива надо доставать значения по ключу, и не только по одному, то `array_column` будет оптимальным вариантом.