# Как найти значение(ссылку) в массиве и удалить по этому пути файл на сервере?

Tags: php

Всем привет!

Не получается достать ссылку на файл чтобы удалить его с сервера. Чтобы удалить запись из массива я сделал.

```
$array = unserialize($list['video']);
//print_r($array);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1644230120
            [1] => Первая запись
            [2] => https://upload.site.ru/video/videotest.mp4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1644230305
            [1] => Вторая запись
            [2] => https://upload.site.ru/video/ScreenStreamMp4.mp4
        )

)

//ищу ключ по значению и получаю ключ массива в котором находится это значение
$keys = array_keys(array_combine(array_keys($array), array_column($array, '0')), $num);

//Удаляю нужную запись из массива
unset($array[$keys[0]]);
```

Однако мне еще нужно удалить файл из директории на сервере а для этого нужен полный путь к файлу. А чтобы узнать путь нужно достать ссылку по вложенному ключу [2].

Пробовал узнать индекс массива в котором есть значение

```
$a = array_search($array[$keys[0]], $array);
//Получаю 1
```

Ссылку я изначально знать не могу, т.к знаю только

```
$num = $_POST['num'];//уникальный id видео
```

А мне нужно получить ссылку `https://upload.site.ru/video/ScreenStreamMp4.mp4` чтобы удалить файл из директории.

```
unlink('полный путь к файлу');
```

Спасибо!

**РЕШЕНИЕ**
В общем нашел в соседнем вопросе решение.
[Поиск в двумерном массиве - PHP](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851894/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-php)

И сделал так, не знаю насколько это практично с точки зрения большого объема данных.

```
$newArray = array_column($array, '2', '0'); // '2' искомое значение ключа //'0' поиск по ключу
$link = (isset($newArray[$num])) ? $newArray[$num] : NULL; // поиск ссылки
```

Comment: Обойди `$array` форычем и найдя нужный ключ, сделай что надо и с файлом и со всем остальным.

Comment: Для большого объема данных этот подход может вызвать проблемы. Почему? Потому что функция `array_column` __обходит весь массив__ и генерирует __новый массив__.  Если нужный тебе ключ находится __первым__ или __вторым__ в массиве из 50-100-... элементов, то ты делаешь лишнюю работу: вместо того чтобы сделать `break` после первого-второго элемента - обходишь весь массив. Таким образом тратишь время на обход и память на хранение новой структуры.